# Is my texture gone if I accidently clicked on "blank" in UV mapping?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I accidently clicked on the "blank" button in the UV editor. I had a texture I painted in texture paint mode in the last two hours and I didn't save it. Is it really gone now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately it's gone forever. Hopefully there will be a day where you can undo that, but in the meantime you should save your images often or paint your textures in another app. There are lots of decent texture painting softwares out there: Mudbox, Mari Indie, 3D Coat, Mari, Substance Painter, Quixel Suite, Bodypaint, and so on, and most of them have better layer management than Blender and care more about keeping your data intact.

If you pick Mudbox make sure to turn up Brush Sample Area under Painting in the prefs. The other apps have sane defaults. If you stick with Blender (which is actually not a bad choice) just make sure to constantly ask yourself, If Blender crashed right now or my image disappeared, would I cry?

Comment: Haha, the last sentence is simply true! Thank you for your great answer, I will definetely check out your recommendations!